# git rebase and reset commits to source branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I want to rebase my `my-branch` to `staging-branch`

```
A---B---C---D---E                  staging-branch
         \
          A5---A4---A3---A2---A1   my-branch
```

After rebasing, I want to get all their commits and then mine.

```
A---B---C---D---E                            staging-branch
         
A---B---C---D---E---A5---A4---A3---A2---A1   my-branch
```

Then I want to combine all commits as two commits.

```
A---B---C---D---E---A11---A22   my-branch
```

I could group all my commits as one using following commands below but not sure how I can split into two.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~5
git commit --edit -m"A11"
git push origin my-branch
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the logic behind the formation of _two_ commits?

Comment: admin wants my PR with two commits.. (logically separated). If I can get rebase done, I can manually commit my changes in two steps.

Comment: This does not provide a needed clarification to your question.

Comment: short answer is : use `git rebase -i staging-branch` and read the instructions at the bottom of the file that appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interactive rebase and edit the todo list accordingly:

```
git rebase -i staging-branch my-branch
```

This will open a text editor with a todo list, which defines which commits should be rebased and what action to take with each of the commits. By default, all actions are `pick`:

```
pick A5 commit message 5
pick A4 commit message 4
pick A3 commit message 3
pick A2 commit message 2
pick A1 commit message 1
```

You can now replace the `pick` action with `fixup`/`f` (combines two commits into one) or `squash`/`s` (combines two commits and lets you edit the commit message). For instance:

```
pick A5 commit message 5
f A4 commit message 4
f A3 commit message 3
pick A2 commit message 2
f A1 commit message 1
```

This instructs git rebase to combine commits 5, 4 and 3; and combine commits 2 and 1.

Once you are satisfied with your todo list, save and exit the editor and rebase will do its work. If there are conflicts, you have to resolve them manually and then run `git rebase --continue`.

With above's todo list, you will eventually end up with the following history:

```
A---B---C---D---E              < staging-branch
                 \
                  A543---A21   < my-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interactive rebase](https://hackernoon.com/beginners-guide-to-interactive-rebasing-346a3f9c3a6d) to reorder the commits based on your logic and squash them into two separate commits. The entire thing can look something like this

```
git checkout my-branch
git rebase staging-branch 
git rebase -i // reorder the commits and use squash to merge them and save the file
```